# SAPUI5 - MVC CRUD Table No data

Tags: sapui5

Created a sapui5 MVC CRUD application i need your help.

1. **Why is there No Data in the view?**
2. **Is it a binding problem?**
3. **Is my CRUD.view.xml correct?**
4. **How can i call JSON data on seperate file? sap.ui.resource() or jQuery.sap.getModulePath()**
5. **What are the solutions?**

*CRUD.controller.js onInit function*

```
  onInit: function () {

    // JSON data normally on a seperate file
    var oData = {
            ApplicationCollection : [
        {
          "applicationId" : "0001",
          "name" : "John Doe",
          "connectionPath" : "index.html",
          "imagePath" : "Image Path",
          "subApplicationId": "Sub ID",
          "status": "active"
        },
        {
          "applicationId" : "0002",
          "name" : "Jane Doe",
          "connectionPath" : "index.html",
          "imagePath" : "Image Path",
          "subApplicationId": "Sub ID",
          "status": "active"
        },
        {
          "applicationId" : "0003",
          "name" : "Mary Jane",
          "connectionPath" : "index.html",
          "imagePath" : "Image Path",
          "subApplicationId": "Sub ID",
          "status": "active"
        },
        {
          "applicationId" : "0004",
          "name" : "Bob Foo",
          "connectionPath" : "index.html",
          "imagePath" : "Image Path",
          "subApplicationId": "Sub ID",
          "status": "active"
        }
      ]
    };

    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    oModel.setData(oData);
    this.getView().setModel(oModel);
  }
```

*CRUD.view.xml*

```
<mvc:View
   controllerName="sap.ui.crud.view.CRUD"
   xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
   xmlns="sap.m">
    <Table
      id="idProductsTable"
      inset="false"
      items="{
        path: '/ApplicationCollection'      
      }">
     <headerToolbar>
       ...
     </headerToolbar>
     <columns> <!-- Columns Header -->
       ...
     </columns> <!-- End of Columns Header -->
     <items> <!-- Column List -->
       <ColumnListItem>
        <cells>
          <Text
            text="{applicationId}" />
          <Text
            text="{name}" />
          <Text
            text="{connectionPath}" />
          <Text
            text="{imagePath}" />
          <Text
            text="{subApplicationId}" />  
          <Text 
            text="{status}" />            
        </cells>
      </ColumnListItem>
     </items> <!-- End of Column List -->
   </Table>

</mvc:View>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Simply use `<Table ... items="{/ApplicationCollection}">...` and it should work
2. Not necessarily, just wrong syntax ;-)
3. Yup, should work just fine!
4. Why not use

   ```
   var oAnotherModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("resources/your_other.json");
   this.getView().setModel(oAnotherModel);
   ```

I'm not entirely sure what you mean with 5) though, can you elaborate a bit more?

EDIT: See a your code working here : http://jsbin.com/biyiq/1/edit

Comment: 1. Didn't work still no data.  4. tried it and generated a parse error  Do i need to configure something in Component.js for the JSON data.

Comment: 1. See my update answer above, there must be something else wrong in your code then. 4. No, should work just as expected. Is your JSON file valid?

Comment: Q1. I have it working in a JS view version but not in XML. yes i change it in to {/ApplicatonCollection}.  Q4. I'm sure its valid. hmmm perhaps I'll try again or try to clear my browsing data.

Comment: Strange... do you see any differences between my code and your code with respect to the bindings?